Fast computation of asymptotic of Taylor coefficients of a rational function
Suppose I want to find the (possible) asymptotic(s) of a linear recurrence, but I don't know the initial conditions. I can write down the ordinary generating function of the solution, which will be rational; suppose, for instance, it has the form
$$f(z) = \frac{r_{2}{z}^2 + r_{1}z + r_{0}}{1- z - 4z^{3}}$$
In this specific problem, I could consider all essentially different combinations of coefficients $r_{2}, r_{1}, r_{0}$ and write down the partial fraction decomposition in each case. I could then calculate explicit formulae for the $n$-th coefficient of the Taylor decomposition. However, I wonder if there is a faster analytical way to obtain the asymptotic of these coefficients, perhaps via some kind of complex magic.
P.S. I could also find the asymptotic by finding the Jordan's decomposition of the matrix of the linear recurrence, but what I am asking is, essentially, "is there a fast way to find the asymptotic of Taylor coefficients of a rational function".

Darboux's method: https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10#iv

@Gary, I will investigate this, thank you!

You can use the explicit solution formula that is derived from the characteristic polynomial of the recurrence. In your case, $\lambda^3 - \lambda^2-4$ has three roots, and the largest of them by absolute value is $2$, so the answer is something like $\max(r_0, 2r_1, 4r_2)2^n$, or just $O(2^n)$.

Thank you, but my question was about asymptotics of Taylor coefficients of a rational function. The example of recurrence is just for motivation.

It's essentially $O(n^{k-1} \lambda^n)$, where $\lambda$ is the root of the "reversed" denominator with highest absolute value, and $k$ is its multiplicity.

Kulkov, I will work this out, thank you
